# NestJS @Injectable used in a global object: use 'new injectable' or 'app.use(injectable)'?

Tags: nestjs

As NestJS allows injection I want to make sure I write the most efficient code.

I'm using a global interceptor to wrap my app responses and a global filter to process the exceptions.

```
//main.ts:
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ResponseWrapperInterceptor(app.get(LogService)));
app.useGlobalFilters(new ExceptionsFilter(app.get(LogService)));
```

```
//filter/interceptor.ts:
constructor(@Inject('LogService') private readonly logger: LogService) {}
```

In my main.ts, what is more efficient? What is the impact for both options? Is there a better way?

```
//Option 1:
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ResponseWrapperInterceptor(app.get(LogService)));
app.useGlobalFilters(new ExceptionsFilter(app.get(LogService)));
```

or

```
//Option 2:
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ResponseWrapperInterceptor(new LogService()));
app.useGlobalFilters(new ExceptionsFilter(new LogService()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to much about the impact or which way is better; however, if you're looking for a way to let Nest handle the dependency injections so you don't have to, you can register your interceptor and filter in your AppModule as follows:

```
@Module({
  imports: [/* your imports here*/],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: ResponseWrapperInterceptor
    }, {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: ExceptionsFilter
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Where `APP_INTERCEPTOR` and `APP_FILTER` are imported from `@nestjs/core`. [You can read more about it here](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Yes, that was my first approach, but this both filter and interceptor will be used for every single module in my app, I don't want to declare them in every module if it's not needed. The goal is to have a set of common modules I can reuse in all my new REST API in an easy way to log and wrap exceptions and responses. For that purpose, it's easier to just mark them as global in the main

Comment: This will still create a global interceptor to be used across the app. Quote from the documentation: `When using this approach to perform dependency injection for the interceptor, note that regardless of the module where this construction is employed, the interceptor is, in fact, global.` It should still be a global interceptor and filter for your application when binding this way

Comment: If I put it in the AppModule yes, you are right. Both approaches work, maybe I should do some profiling and check the speed and memory usage for big loads. Thanks!